# Swift / How to add a String to a method to make it generic

Tags: ios, swift

I have the follow code to handle swipe gestures.

```
    import Foundation

extension UIViewController {
    func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if (sender.direction == .Right) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("eventsModally", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

I call the method with:

```
    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
    rightSwipe.direction = .Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
```

What is the best practise to make the Extension usable in other Controller with other Segue-names?

I tought about that:

```
func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer, segueName:String) {
        if (sender.direction == .Right) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueName, sender: self)
        }
    }
```

But how do I call the new method and give it the Segue name: "eventsModally", "infoModally", etc...?

Comment: my problem is, that I don't know how to use it. `let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))`How do I give this code the string for the desired Segue?

Comment: In your scenario, it actually would make more sense to subclass or extend `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` than to extend `UIViewController`

Comment: okay can you give me an example of what would be the best practise?

Comment: I'll try it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you subclass `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, and use a internal class to store the forwarding logic, something in the like of this:

```
class MySwipeGestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

    private let internalTarget: SegueGestureTarget

    init(target: UIViewController, swipeLeftSegue: String?, swipeRightSeque: String?) {
        self.internalTarget = SegueGestureTarget(target: target, swipeLeftSegue: swipeLeftSegue, swipeRightSeque: swipeRightSeque)

        super.init(target: internalTarget, action: "handleSwipes:")
    }

    class SegueGestureTarget: NSObject {

        private weak var target: UIViewController?
        private let swipeLeftSegue: String?
        private let swipeRightSeque: String?

        init(target: UIViewController, swipeLeftSegue: String?, swipeRightSeque: String?) {
            self.target = target
            self.swipeLeftSegue = swipeLeftSegue
            self.swipeRightSeque = swipeRightSeque
        }

        func handleSwipes(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
            if let swipeLeftSegue = self.swipeLeftSegue where sender.direction == .Left {
                target?.performSegueWithIdentifier(swipeLeftSegue, sender: self)
            }
            if let swipeRightSeque = self.swipeRightSeque where sender.direction == .Right {
                target?.performSegueWithIdentifier(swipeRightSeque, sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var swipeGestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Assumes 'swipeLeft' and 'swipeRight' segues are defined in a .XIB 
        swipeGestureRecognizer = MySwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self,
            swipeLeftSegue: "swipeLeft",
            swipeRightSeque: "swipeRight")

        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGestureRecognizer!)
    }
}
```

Comment: it works perfect. thank you for the high effort and I hope you'll receive plenty more upvotes on this one.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this way:

```
class BaseViewControllerExample: UIViewController {
  private var _onGoingVCName: String?
  private func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if let nameVC = _onGoingVCName {
      if (sender.direction == .Right) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(nameVC, sender: self)
      }
    }
  }

  private func setSwipeGestureForModelName(name:String) {
    _onGoingVCName = name
    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
    rightSwipe.direction = .Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
  }
}

class ViewControllerExample: BaseViewControllerExample {
  func example() {
    setSwipeGestureForModelName("ABC")
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry that i didnt gave you an upvote back then. just caught up. thanks for your effort

Comment: @DavidSeek you're so polite. Thank you.